# Perl to substitute string with a string containing spaces and double quotes

Tags: string, bash, perl, quotes

My bash script builds a string variable `$arrayLMEs`, containing a string like:

```
var availableTags=[ "01 East Bering Sea", "02 Gulf of Alaska"];
```

I need to put this string in a javascript code, to replace a placeholder.
I was thinking to use something like:

```
perl -i -pe 's/PLACEHOLDER/'"${arrayLMEs}"'/' filename
```

But actually the command complains, because of the double quotes found in the string, which are messing up the bash command and in consequence the perl command.

How can I fix the command to keep the spaces and double quotes?

Comment: I don't see any problem when running on bash on Linux:

arrayLMEs='var availableTags=[ "01 East Bering Sea", "02 Gulf of Alaska"];';
echo --PLACEHOLDER-- | perl -pe 's/PLACEHOLDER/'"${arrayLMEs}"'/' -

Comment: I must say that my strings are generated. So I guess that the quotes happen to be stripped out when passed from a command to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-s` switch to pass the variable to perl:

```
perl -spe 's/PLACEHOLDER/$var/' -- -var="$arrayLMEs" filename
```

The `--` signifies the end of the command line arguments. `-var="$arrayLMEs"` sets a perl variable with the value of your shell variable `$arrayLMEs`.

Alternatively, you could use awk:

```
awk -v var="$arrayLMEs" '{sub(/PLACEHOLDER/, var)}1' filename
```

A nice side-effect of using awk is the replacement is a simple string, so metacharacters in the original string won't be interpreted.

Comment: This is an original solution. I never thought about using `-s` for one-liners!

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I found a workaround (but not as good as Tom Fenech's solution).

1. Save the variable in a file

   `echo $arrayLMEs > tmpfile`
2. use sed to paste the file content into the target file

   `sed -i '/PLACEHOLDER/{
   r tmpfile
   d
   }' filename`

I suppose that it is quite robust. Downside: forces to create another file on the fly.